# AWS certificate resolver for Traefik Ingress Controller in K3S Kubernetes Cluster with existing AWS HTTPS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, traefik, amazon-elb, k3s

1. I have AWS K3S Kubernetes Cluster
2. I have AWS Load Balancer
3. I have registered domain
4. I have registered AWS Certificate
5. I created CNAME record for my domain and for AWS Load Balancer DNS name
6. I installed Traefik Ingress Controller on AWS K3S Kubernetes Cluster
7. I deployed "usermgmt" and "whoami" services to AWS K3S Kubernetes Cluster
8. I created Traefik Ingress with paths to "usermgmt" and "whoami"

The question is:

> How to connect my AWS Load Balancer, which is hosted on my domain, to my services on K3s, using Ingress Traefik Controller?

Or in other words:

> How to adapt "traefik service" or "traefik deployment", described below, to use AWS Certificate Resolver for my registered domain?

Or any example of how to use

> - AWS Load Balancer, AWS Target Group, AWS Security Group, created with Terraform files
> - in combination with Traefik Ingress Controller and Traefik Ingress Routes, deployed to K3S Kubernetes Cluster, resolved with AWS Certificate.

I currently can't connect to my services through AWS Load Balancer.
The following errors are returned:

```
404 Page Not Found

502 Bad Gateway
```

Here are the examples of URLs, which I try:

```
https://keycloak.skycomposer.net/usermgmt
https://keycloak.skycomposer.net/whoami
```

I set up correspondent Ingress Routes for "usermgmt" and "whoami" kubernetes services.

Here is some more information:

- **I created K3S Kubernetes Cluster in AWS with Load Balancer**

These are my terraform files:
https://github.com/skyglass/user-management/tree/master/terraform

K3S cluster is deployed to **EC2 instance** (see "**userdata.tpl**" script)

I disabled **Traefik Ingress Controller** deployment, so I could deploy it later.

- **I found example on how to install "Traefik" to K3S Kubernetes cluster here:**
  https://github.com/sleighzy/k3s-traefik-v2-kubernetes-crd

Unfortunately, this example uses "**godaddy**" certificate resolver, but my domain is registered with **AWS Route 53** and I use **AWS certificate manager**.

Here are files for "**traefik service**" and "**traefik deployment**", which I try to adapt:

**traefik-service:**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system

spec:
  # The targetPort entries are required as the Traefik container is listening on ports > 1024
  # so that the container can be run as a non-root user and they can bind to these ports.
  # Traefik is still accessed over 80 and 443 on the host, but the service routes the traffic
  # to ports 8080 and 8443 on the container.
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      name: websecure
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
    - protocol: TCP
      name: admin
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 9080
  selector:
    app: traefik
  # Set externalTrafficPolicy to Local so that all external traffic intended for
  # the Traefik pod goes directly to that local node. If the default of Cluster is
  # used instead then the client source IP address is lost, and may hop between nodes.
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**traefik-deployment:**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: traefik-ingress-controller

---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: traefik
  labels:
    app: traefik

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v2.4
          args:
            - --api.dashboard=true
            - --ping=true
            - --accesslog
            - --entrypoints.traefik.address=:9080
            - --entrypoints.web.address=:8080
            - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:8443
            # Uncomment the below lines to redirect http requests to https.
            # This specifies the port :443 and not the https entrypoint name for the
            # redirect as the service is listening on port 443 and directing traffic
            # to the 8443 target port. If the entrypoint name "websecure" was used,
            # instead of "to=:443", then the browser would be redirected to port 8443.
            - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=:443
            - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
            - --providers.kubernetescrd
            - --providers.kubernetesingress
            - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true
            - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=postmaster@example.com
            - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/etc/traefik/certs/acme.json          
            # Please note that this is the staging Let's Encrypt server.
            # Once you get things working, you should remove that whole line altogether.
            # - --certificatesresolvers.godaddy.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
            - --log
            - --log.level=INFO
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /ping
              port: 9080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: '100Mi'
              cpu: '1000m'
          ports:
            # The Traefik container is listening on ports > 1024 so the container
            # can be run as a non-root user and they can bind to these ports.
            - name: web
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: websecure
              containerPort: 8443
            - name: admin
              containerPort: 9080
          volumeMounts:
            - name: certificates
              mountPath: /etc/traefik/certs
      # volumes:
      #   - name: certificates
      #     persistentVolumeClaim:
      #       claimName: traefik-certs-pvc              
      volumes:
        - name: certificates
          hostPath:
            path: "/Users/dddd/git/aws/letsencrypt:/etc/traefik/certs"
```

See other files here: https://github.com/sleighzy/k3s-traefik-v2-kubernetes-crd

Ideally there should be solution like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-proxy
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:REGION:ACCOUNTID:certificate/CERT-ID"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: traefik-proxy
    tier: proxy
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 80
```

In this solution, I would just provide my AWS Certificate ARN and traefik ingress controller will do everything else.

The similar solution is described in this article:

https://www.ronaldjamesgroup.com/blog/getting-started-with-traefik

But, unfortunately, this solution doesn't work for me too, I tried it without any success.

The following errors are returned:

```
404 Page Not Found

502 Bad Gateway
```

when I try Ingress Route Paths for my domain:

```
https://keycloak.skycomposer.net/usermgmt
https://keycloak.skycomposer.net/whoami
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying several options, I finally found the solution:
https://github.com/skyglass-examples/aws-k3s-traefik

1. I created **AWS Load Balancer** and **K3S cluster** with **Terraform**
2. I created **Traefik Ingress Controller** kubernetes manifest files
3. I created **kubernetes manifest files** for 2 services
4. I registered **AWS Load Balancer DNS** name for my domain
5. I created **AWS Certificate** for my domain
6. I used **AWS Certificate ARN** for **Traefik Ingress Controller** and **AWS HTTPS Load Balancer**

Here are my **Traefik Ingress Controller** manifest files:

**traefik-deployment.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system


---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-proxy
  namespace: kube-system     
  labels:
    app: traefik-proxy
    tier: proxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik-proxy
      tier: proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik-proxy
        tier: proxy
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller   
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: traefik:v1.2.0-rc1-alpine
        name: traefik-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
          name: traefik-proxy
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: traefik-ui
        args:
          - --web
          - --kubernetes
```

**traefik-service.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-proxy
  namespace: kube-system   
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:us-west-1:dddddddddd"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "http"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "0.0.0.0/0"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "alb"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local  
  selector:
    app: traefik-proxy
    tier: proxy
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
  namespace: kube-system     
spec:
  selector:
    app: traefik-proxy
    tier: proxy
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
```

**traefik-ingress.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: traefik-lb
spec:
  controller: traefik.io/ingress-controller

---
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "traefik-usermgmt-ingress"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "traefik-lb"
  rules:
  - host: "keycloak.skycomposer.net"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/usermgmt"
        backend:
          serviceName: "usermgmt"
          servicePort: 80


---
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "traefik-whoami-ingress"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "traefik-lb"
  rules:
  - host: "keycloak.skycomposer.net"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/whoami"
        backend:
          serviceName: "whoami"
          servicePort: 80
```

See the **full code** here:
https://github.com/skyglass-examples/aws-k3s-traefik

The code includes:

1. **terraform** files for **AWS Load Balancer** and **K3S Kubernetes Cluster**
2. **source code** for one of the **docker containers**, which I deployed to **K3S**
3. kubernetes manifest files for **Traefik Ingress Controller**, **2 Kubernetes Services** and **Traefik Ingress**, which exposes these services with **secured HTTPS connection** on registered domain.
4. Replace **AWS Certificate ARN** with correspondent **ARN of your certificate**
5. Replace "**skycomposer.net**" with **your domain name** (see more details in the **Readme file**:  https://github.com/skyglass-examples/aws-k3s-traefik)